# One-sided limits for Greatest Integer Function evaluating to 0 / 0

Tags: calculus, limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm currently taking introduction to Calculus and I've been presented with this limit involving the greatest integer function (GIF):

$$\lim_{x \to 2^-} \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1}{\lfloor x \rfloor - x}$$

Now since $x \to 2^-$ I figured I could immediately evaluate the limits of the first terms of the numerator and denominator and replace it with 1. This makes the numerator 0 and the denominator will be $1 - x$. After evaluating the limit of the denominator I arrive at $\frac{0}{-1}$ which is basically 0. However looking at the problem's answer keys it said that the limit should have been $-\infty$. I wasn't sure where I got it wrong so I thought that the key must be wrong for that item until I tried solving for this next limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{\lfloor x^2 \rfloor - \lfloor x \rfloor^2}{x^2 - 1}$$

Since $x \to 1^+$, I thought that $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ would both resolve to 1 right? And that's what I did but the limit of the entire function then becomes an indeterminate form of type $\frac{0}{0}$. Now I know that I should rewrite the function in order to get rid of the terms that would cause it to become $\frac{0}{0}$ and factoring the denominator gives me $(x + 1)(x - 1)$ which will become $(2)(0^+)$ but given that the numerator is 0, isn't that the same indeterminate form? The answer key says that the limit is 0.

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to manipulate or rewrite these GIF that simply hasn't been taught to us?

**EDIT**

If you guys think that the question or the answer key must be wrong then please feel free to tell me :) I'm preparing for the exam tomorrow and I don't want to be bogged down thinking about these limits if they're wrong. I got most of the problems correctly and it's only these two that's been weird for me, I've tried what I can but I'm just stumped. I'm currently googling ways to rewrite the GIF function.

Comment: Are you certain that, for the first one, it is not $x\to 2^+$? (For the second one, for any $x\in (1,\sqrt{2})$, the numerator is $0$ and the denominator is $x^2-1>0$, so the quantity is $0$. So the overall limit will be $0$, since the function is identically zero on $(1,1+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$).

Comment: Yep, our module only has answers for odd-numbered questions and the question before that one has $x \to 2^+$ which I know is $-\infty$ that's why I dismissed the answer key as wrong for the first question until I saw the next limit that gave me problems.

Comment: For the second one, think of it this way: $\lim_{x\to1^+} \frac{0}{x^2-1} = ?$

Comment: I see, shouldn't I care that the limit of denominator is 0 and thus the entire function has the form $\frac{0}{0}$? edit: I think I see what you're saying, it's not $\frac{0}{0}$ exactly but $\frac{0}{0^+}$?

Comment: The limit of the denominator is zero, but that is not relevant since the numerator is **exactly** zero. Even if you multiply $0$ by a quantity increasingly big, the product will still be exactly $0$ (not that you don't "multiply by $\infty$": you multiply by something *which tends to $\infty$*)

Comment: If for every $1 < x < \sqrt{2}$ we have $f(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1^+} 0 = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get it now. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad this cleared the doubts :)

Comment: @R.Cruz It's simpler if you recall that in the definition of a limit we're not at all interested what the function is doing *at* the limit point, but rather in a neighborhood of it. In this case, $x^2 - 1$ is never zero in an interval $(1, \varepsilon)$ as Clement C. correctly showed.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I was too hung up in checking for indeterminate forms first that I forgot to look at he behavior of the function as it's approaching 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, you're right and the answer key would be for $x \to 2^+$. To see why, observe that we can work in the interval $(1, 2)$. Here, $\lfloor x \rfloor - 1 = 0$, and so the limit is $0$ if the denominator is not $0$. Indeed, that's exactly what happens, since $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ is the *fractional part* function, that's $0$ only at the integers. Since there are no integers in $(1, 2)$, the limit is $0$.

For the second limit, we can apply the same reasoning with the interval $(1, \sqrt 2)$. Here, the numerator is identically zero, while the denominator is never zero. Hence, the limit evaluates to $0$ once again.